# Liquibase error Could not find databaseChangeLog node

Tags: liquibase

I am new to Liquibase. I'm trying to set it up and still getting error messages when running the following command:

```
/opt/liquibase2/liquibase updateSQL >> output.sql
```

The error message is:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not find databaseChangeLog node
```

Below my `liquibase.properties` file:

```
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
classpath=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/opt/liquibase2/lib/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:lb_demo/lb_demo@myServer:1521/IbzPerfEE
changeLogFile=changelog/db.changelog-master.json
```

`myServer` is the hostname of the database server. `IbzPerfEE` is the database instance name.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your changelog file contain?

Answer (score 2):

The most parent "node" of your change.json must be a node namend "databaseChangeLog"